# How to read Variables from platform.sh on Gatsby site at build time

Tags: gatsby, platform.sh

I am working on a gatsby site. In that I have  to  get  configuration
related  values from variables which are declared in platform.sh variable.

I have tried following approach to read value from platform.sh:

```
    const { env } = process;

// Utility to assist in decoding a packed JSON variable.
function read_base64_json(varName) {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(Buffer.from(env[varName], "base64").toString());
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(`no ${varName} environment variable`);
  }
};

// A simple variable.
let projectId = env.PLATFORM_PROJECT;

// A JSON-encoded value.
let variables = read_base64_json('PLATFORM_VARIABLES');
```

but it always returns an empty object in **PLATFORM_VARIABLES** .

**Another approach:**

I have also tried `platformsh-config` npm In that I tried to get value using
following code:

```
    const config = require('platformsh-config').config();
    
    // A JSON-encoded value.
    let variables =config.variables();
```

but it also returns an empty object